# Symfony project cloned with git vendors not installed

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php

I started my symfony project on a Fedora guest and coded happily for several time. Then I've exported my file to an amazon EC2 VM thanks to koding.com and coded there for some time (it's handy). I finally would like to be able to code from any environment so I set up git and have all my files there.

Yesterday, I cloned my repository from github into my Fedora guest and tried to launch it. It doesn't work for some vendors library aren't installed.

I've read the doc and that would be normal, after cloning a repository one has to do a php composer.phar install.

I've tried but I get an error message because the vendors libraries are declare in my AppKernel

```
php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle' not found in /home/eagle1/www/ICORECO/app/AppKernel.php on line 29
```

so I tried commenting these lines but obviously I got code that extends this classes so again composer install generates an error

```
php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file                                                                                          [LogicException]                                                                              
  Bundle "NRtworksSubscriptionBundle" extends bundle "FOSUserBundle", which is not registered.
```

what can I do ?

This is my .gitignore

```
# Cache and logs (Symfony2)
/app/cache/*
/app/logs/*
!app/cache/.gitkeep
!app/logs/.gitkeep
# Cache and logs (Symfony3)
/var/cache/*
/var/logs/*
!var/cache/.gitkeep
!var/logs/.gitkeep
# Parameters
/app/config/parameters.yml
/app/config/parameters.ini
# Managed by Composer
/app/bootstrap.php.cache
/var/bootstrap.php.cache
/bin/*
!bin/console
!bin/symfony_requirements
/vendor/
# Assets and user uploads
/web/bundles/
/web/uploads/
# PHPUnit
/app/phpunit.xml
/phpunit.xml
# Build data
/build/
# Composer PHAR
```

Comment: do you have your ``composer.lock`` file in place? Did you try do do ``composer update`` instead?

Comment: yes I have a composer.lock and composer update just does the same result

Comment: and are you sure you have FOSUserBundle in composer.json registered? Maybe ``cache:clear`` will help

Comment: I removed the line and did "php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0@dev"" it gives me the exact same error as in my question

Comment: Is your `vendor/` directory being tracked by Git?

Comment: the folder itself yes but subdirectories like /vendor/friendsofsymphony no, that's the point of my post.

Comment: @Eagle1, in general, `vendor/` should *not* be versioned. Try removing the directory, then running `composer install`. If that fixes things up I'll write a proper answer for you.

Comment: not they should not, I provided in my question my .gitignore file. Don't know why they were uploaded. It seems that even if I have just empty folders, composer doesn't install the content if a folder exist, messing everything up. so yes you can write and answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your `vendor/` directory is in an inconsistent state.

In general, Composer [recommends not versioning `vendor/`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md). Your [`composer.json` and `composer.lock` files  should both be committed](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file), and Composer can build `vendor/` from these files.

I recommend deleting `vendor/` and running `composer install` again to rebuild it from scratch. Assuming that `composer.json` and `composer.lock` are correct, this should get you back to a working state.

Then makes sure that you are ignoring `vendor/`, e.g. with a line such as

```
vendor/
```

in your `.gitignore`, and remove any vendor files that may have been accidentally committed to the repository:

```
git rm --cached -r vendor
```

Comment: indeed that was the issue. It appears even an empty folder is enough for composer to consider the dependency as being installed