# Install FOSUserBundle after cloning from Git

Tags: php, git, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've created my own site on my local computer and it works wonderfully.  I'm having tons of fun developing with it.  But when it came time to move it to my server and test I ran into issue.

I'm using the FOSUserBundle.  Obviously being a Git of it's own, when I did a git commit and push, git ignored everything in vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle.  So when I cloned to my server, the folder came empty, and of course now my site doesn't work.

I want to do this the right way.  So if it means destroying the git repo and doing it a different way, I'm ok with that.

So far I've tried.

1. Following the original install instructions for FOSUserBundle
2. Running the following:

   `composer update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle`

   `composer install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle`

Both return "nothing to update/install"

I've also tried clearing composer's cache between each command attempt.

```
rm -rf ~/.composer/cache
```

Comment: Is your `vendor/` directory being tracked by Git?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use git submodules. That occurs when you have a parent git repository (in this case your own website) within which you have a child repository (FOSUserBundle). Is that right?

Comment: Chris:  Yes my vendor/ is being tracked should it not be?

Comment: Shaun:  Sounds right to me,  there's a .git file in the vendors/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle  which was originally installed using composer

Comment: Cool. You'll want to read this: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: @Squeegy, it should not be. I just answered almost exactly this question this afternoon... duplicate incoming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony project cloned with git vendors not installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451023/symfony-project-cloned-with-git-vendors-not-installed)

Comment: Thanks @Chris and I wasn't sure what to look for and I think that might be it.  Let me give it a shot!

Comment: BTW, Shaun's advice is generally good, but if you are using Composer as it's meant to be used you shouldn't have trouble with submodules.

Comment: @Chris Worked like a charm  Thanks to Shaun too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is in the comments.  Ignore vendor/ use composer to install the appropriate files.

also this [Symfony project cloned with git vendors not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451023/symfony-project-cloned-with-git-vendors-not-installed)

Answer (score -1):

What it *sounds like* your trying to do is create a **mywebsite** parent repo within which you have a third party child repo that has the **FOSUserBundle** code. This uses git submodules and requires related submodule commands like `git submodule init`.

> The ... directory is there, but empty. You must run two commands: git submodule init to initialize your local configuration file, and git submodule update to fetch all the data from that project and check out the appropriate commit listed in your superproject...

I don't know anything about composer. Here is how you could do it with git.

```
cd mywebsite
git init
git submodule add <url-to-FOSUserBundle-repo>
```

You should now have a directory structure like this:

```
 mywebsite
     .git
     .gitmodules
     FOSUserBunder
         .git
```

See also http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules